# Execute terminal command over python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to get the hostname where the `.py` is running, so I used:

```
server = subprocess.Popen(["hostname"])
print(server.stdout)
```

However, I'm getting this return:

```
None
HOSTNAME
```

It always prints a `None` from the `subprocess.Popen()` and then the hostname at `print(server.stdout)`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: No, it's printing `None` from `print(server.stdout)` (because you didn't tell it to capture stdout), and the subprocess is sending `HOSTNAME` directly to your terminal.  You need to add a `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` parameter to `Popen()`.

Comment: Now it's returning ```<Popen: returncode: None args: ['hostname']>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've three solutions so far:

1. Using Popen and stdout.read:

```py
import subprocess
server = subprocess.Popen(["hostname"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(server.stdout.read().decode().rstrip("\n"))
```

2. Using Popen and communicate

```py
import subprocess
server = subprocess.Popen(["hostname"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = server.communicate()
print(out.decode().rstrip("\n"))
```

3. Using check_output:

```py
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output("hostname").decode().rstrip("\n"))
```

I'm wondering if you can get a string directly, but it works.

Comment: To remove the b' prefix and \n' suffix should I use .replace?

Comment: Hold, up, I'll change it for you.

Comment: The server runs python 3.6. Is there an alternative for removesuffix()?

Comment: Sure, use rstrip or strip since it's just one character.

Comment: Like ```str(server.stdout.read()).rstrip("b'\n")```?

Comment: No, I've updated the response. (You should use decode)